# Restricting the list of voice commands on Android to a predefined set

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, microphone

For Android, we have Google's voice input api's where we speak into the microphone and it outputs k most likely things that we said.  Is there a way that, instead, we give voice input a set of valid "commands" or sentences and it outputs the most likely one?

For example, a list of valid commands would be:

"Play song"
"Pause"
"Next"
"Previous"

However, no other words in the language would be considered as options.

Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive that with [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/), it could take a grammar specifying the language to recognize as a parameter for decoder:

```
            c.setString("-jsgf","grammar.jsgf");
```

The grammar is specified in [JSGF format](http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/).